# Why the edge Rect of a `div` can be smaller than the content Rect of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

The only difference of the two block of  codes below is

```css
.parent::after{
   content: " ";
   display:table;
}
```

Why the edge Rect of a `div` can be smaller than the content Rect of it?
What's more?
I can't understand why the edge Rect of a `div` which can be detected by the `other` decorated is the same between the two,but the content Rect differs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="other"></div>
   

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .parent{
            width: 200px;
            background-color: beige;
        }
        .parent::after{
            content: " ";
            display:table;
        }
        .child {
            width: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: pink;
            margin-bottom: -20px;
        }
        .other{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #86cfef3b;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="other"></div>
   

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .parent{
            width: 200px;
            background-color: beige;
        }
       
        .child {
            width: 100px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: pink;
            margin-bottom: -20px;
        }
        .other{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #86cfef3b;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

## section two

To get rid of the confluence of the negative margin, I made these codes.

The same ,the only difference of the two block of  codes below is

```css
.parent::after{
   content: " ";
   display:table;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="other"></div>
       

  
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .parent{
                width: 200px;
                background-color: beige;
            }
           
            .child {
                width: 100px;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: pink;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .other{
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: #86cfef3b;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="other"></div>
       

    
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .parent{
                width: 200px;
                background-color: beige;
            }
            .parent::after{
                content: " ";
                display:table;
            }
            .child {
                width: 100px;
                height: 80px;
                background-color: pink;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .other{
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: #86cfef3b;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check this gif - on it I change -20px to 20px, so you could get an idea how it is affects the wrapper and see why it does that with negative number: https://dsh.re/a9041

Comment: @extempl Then why the second snippet does not perform like this?

Comment: Negative margins are evil, especially when you combine different `display` properties since different `display` properties handle collapsing margins differently https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing, I'd say to always avoid negative margins (for example, I know grids disable marging collapse for the children, and probably tables do something special too)

Comment: ehhh, I made the margin positive ,can you explain this? @arieljuod

Comment: I don't have a clear explanation for this, I imagine `display: table` changes how the browser interprets collapsing margins, it does also weird things if you use `display: inline-block`. I don't know the CSS specs for collapsing margins combining elements with different `display` values to understand if that's expected or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is your box-sizing. It's not being applied to pseudo-classes. You might want to also add a simple reset to your css. Here's an example:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

You also have a /div tag not associated with another div. It's probably not causing any issues like an open div tag would cause, but you should delete that unnecessary tag.

```
 <div class="other"></div>
       

        </div> <!---Remove this tag--->
        <style>
```

Comment: I've tested. it seems it makes no difference.